# If $2 < x < 6$, which of the following statements about x are necessarily true, and which are not necessarily true?

Tags: inequality

If $2 < x < 6$, which of the following statements about x are necessarily true, and which are not necessarily true?

Just need conformation on this question. Apply the question to $|x-4| < 2$ .
I came up with it is not necessarily true because if $a$ is any positive real number then  $|x| < a$ if and only if $-a < x < a$ . Which does not apply so the answer would be not necessarily right?

Comment: You can subtract $4$ from sides of the inequality to get $-2<x-4<2\Rightarrow |x-4|<2$

Comment: Can you find a value for $x$ such that $2<x<6$ but not $|x-4|<2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$2<x<6$$
$$\iff 2-4<x-4<6-4$$
$$\iff -2<x-4<2$$

$$\iff|x-4|<2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have found that $|x-4| < 2$ if and only if $-2 < x-4 < 2$; by adding four throughout, we obtain that $|x-4| < 2$ if and only if $2 < x < 6$. So the statement is necessarily true (and, in fact, is a sufficient condition for $2<x<6$).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not necessarily true then you should be able to come up with a number $2 < x < 6$ for which $|x - 4| < 2$ does not hold.  Can you?

Answer (score 1):

let $y = x-4$. Then, as you said, we must have
$$ |y| <2 \Leftrightarrow  -2<y <2$$
Since $y = x-4$, we have
$$ -2<x-4<2 \Leftrightarrow 2<x<6.  $$

Comment: FYI: In English it's "as you said" rather than "as you told."

Answer (score 1):

You are almost right. If `|x-4| < 2`, then `-2 < x - 4 < 2`. Adding 4 to both sides gives `2 < x < 6`. Since it is given that `2 < x < 6`, we know that the set of `x` satisfying `|x-4| < 2` is the same set of `x` satisfying `2 < x < 6`.